# R gsub replace several texts at once

Tags: regex, r, gsub

In my data frame there is a column with multiplier indicators, such as thousands, hundreds, millions, etc., **as text**.

I'd like to convert them to numeric. This is what I've tried:

```
a <- c("Thousands", "thousands", "Hundreds", "hundreds")
newA <- as.numeric(gsub("[Tt]housands","1000",gsub("[Hh]undreds","100",a)))
```

Which works, but results very cumbersome when there are many multipliers (as is the case). I was thinking there should be a way to do it in one `gsub` call, but wasn't able to do it. Something like this is what I would like (of course this particular attempt didn't work):

```
as.numeric(gsub("^.*-","",gsub("([Hh]undreds)([Tt]housands)","\\1-100 \\2-1000",a)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
library(qdap)
as.numeric(multigsub(c("[Tt]housands", "[Hh]undreds"), c(1000, 100), fixed = FALSE, a))
```

Or as per suggested by @RichardScriven:

```
library(stringi)
as.numeric(stri_replace_all_regex(a, c("[Tt]housands", "[Hh]undreds"), c(1000, 100), 
                                  vectorize_all = FALSE))
```

Comment: Both approaches work perfectly. The `stringi` one, though, installs a **lot less** dependencies than `qdap`.